# spnego.jar switch from Java 7 to Java 8 cast exception

Tags: java, glassfish, jaas, spnego

I'm using spnego.jar from dfelix with Glassfish 4.1 as filter in web.xml. I asked the question on project forum but did not receive response.

I want to switch from Java 1.7.0_45 to 1.8.0_45 (tried also other 1.8 versions). After switching on a test environment I'm getting the error shown below. Tried also a separate case with simple Java also received case exception.

I'm using same krb5.conf (below), login.conf and keytab file as in 1.7.

Is it incompatible with Java 1.8?

> [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1431425761516] [timeMillis: 1431425776202] [levelValue: 1000] [[
>         WebModule[/ax]Exception starting filter SpnegoHttpFilter
>       java.lang.InstantiationException
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:135)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:5329)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5943)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
>           at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
>           at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
>           at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
>           at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException:   javax.security.auth.login.LoginException:   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException:   java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.Hashtable
>           at sun.security.krb5.Config.get0(Config.java:287)
>           at sun.security.krb5.Config.getString0(Config.java:268)
>           at sun.security.krb5.Config.getAll(Config.java:240)
>           at sun.security.krb5.Config.getKDCList(Config.java:1030)
>           at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:218)
>           at sun.security.krb5.KdcComm.send(KdcComm.java:200)
>           at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:316)
>           at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:361)
>           at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:776)
>           at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
>           at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:161)
>           at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.init(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:196)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:131)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:5329)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5943)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
>           at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
>           at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
>           at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
>           at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
>           at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
>           at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

login.conf:

```
    spnego-server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="ax.keytab"
       principal=development
    storeKey=true;
};
```

krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = LOC.COM
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
    permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
    forwardable = true
    udp_preference_limit = 1 

[realms] 
    LOC.COM = { KDC = ax.loc.com default_domain = LOC.COM } 

[domain_realm] 
    .loc.com = LOC.COM
    loc.com = LOC.COM
    ax.loc.com = AX.LOC.COM
```

Comment: Off-topic thing that caught my eye: you say you use glassfish v4.1, but the stacktrace mentions glassfish v3. That seems fishy.

Comment: Are you talking about `com.sun.enterprise.v3.server` ?

Comment: yes indeed I do. I don't know much about Glassfish so maybe its perfectly normal, but it just seemed rather odd to me. If you put the server's major version in the package name, I'd assume you get a package with v4 in it when running Glassfish 4.x. If I'd then get code with a v3 package, I would start to suspect outdated server libraries are being used.

Comment: it is normal, it appears in glassfish 4.0, 4.1 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reformat the `[realms]` section of `krb5.conf` like this:

```
[realms] 
    LOC.COM = {
        KDC = ax.loc.com
        default_domain = LOC.COM
    }
```

There are some changes to `krb5.conf` parsing in JDK8, and [JDK-7184246 : Simplify Config.get() of krb5](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7184246) looks interesting.  The [diff](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u40/jdk/rev/33e29fbc3e5b) shows significant changes to the line-by-line processing of `krb5.conf`.  This seems to have made your file which was parseable under JDK7, unparsable under JDK8.  I think it now wants to see closing braces on their own lines.

I don't think there's a strict specification for `krb5.conf` but most examples show braces on their own lines and only one assignment per-line.

Comment: It works! - in fact looking at error stack there was `sun.security.krb5.Config.get0` but it was not connected by my mind to format it right - it appears like in java 8 formating krb5.conf is crucial. Now i got `Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)` but this is close than previous.

Comment: This is about defective token issue. There are 2 ways first - downgrade java to 1.8.0_31 it is last working version or wait til fix update. Thanks javabrett for help with problem with separate lines in config.